# Tracking logout time in ASP.net MVC web application

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have a task to implement tracking of user login and logout times. The only real problem we're facing is when and how to get the logout time of user. The application has a logout button but our users often just close the browser and then the user is automatically logged out.

Is there any way to get the time when the session ends?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Session_End` method in global.asax, just take the current time stamp in that method and do what you need to do.

```
protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var date = DateTime.Now();
     //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but the session will hopefully outlive the user's interaction with the site.

Comment: @DavidKemp This will give the time when the session ends, which is what op has asked for. If you wanted to get the time of the users last interaction with the site, one way I've managed to do this in the past is by having an ajax call in setInterval() that polls the server so long as the browser tab is open, then on the server side just take the timestamp.